gedit ignoring gtksourceview syntax language after updating to 24.04
After updating to 24.04 I no longer had the fish shell syntax highlighting on gedit.
The syntax file is both in /usr/share/gtksourceview-5/language-specs/fish.lang and in /usr/share/gtksourceview-4/language-specs/fish.lang , but it does not appear in gedit.
After going through the list of languages on those folders, I see several others that are not present in gedit (neither on the menu nor automatically recognized).
How can I have it again?
infos : gedit - Version 46.2

Same issue here. I also put a .lang file in  the language-specs subfolder of gtksourceview-3.0 and gtksourceview-2.0 to no avail. It seems the lang files are only picked up by gnome-text-editor.

In 24.04 the folder is /usr/share/libgedit-gtksourceview-300/language-specs/

This is what worked for me:
Saved my own (edited) .lang files in the home directory
 ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-4/language-specs

--> highlighters are shown in XED and gnome-text-editor but not in GEDIT.
Then I created a symbolic link to the new folder name:
ln -s ~/.local/share/gtksourceview-4 ~/.local/share/libgedit-gtksourceview-300

Now all highlighters also appear in GEDIT.
